# New iterable with elements from another repeated "e.field" times?

Tags: scala

I want a function that receives an `Iterable` and returns a new one with weighted objects from the initial `Iterable`.

Let me give an example:

An object class (let us call it Weight) has an `Int` value named `times`:

```scala
class Weight(val times: Int)
```

The initial `Iterable` has four elements: `{a, b, c, d}`. The weights are as follows:

- a.times = 3
- b.times = 1
- c.times = 2
- d.times = 2

The resulting iteration would be = `{a, a, a, b, c, c, d, d}`.

I have a very ugly implementation so far:

```scala
def weightedIteration(initial: Iterable[Wheight]): Iterable[Weight] = {
  var list: List[Weight] = Nil
  initial.foreach(weight => {
    for(_ <- 0 until weight.times)
      list :+= weight
  })
  list
}
```

What I really don't like is the var list. I would prefer to yield each element the desired number of times. I tried to put the yield statement into the for expression; but that didn't work well, as the last statement in this method would be the `foreach` expression returning a `Unit`.

Is there any way of using yield in this case? Or returning an iterable out of some Collection Combinator (map)? I don't mind either way as long as I get rid of the var list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for {
    times <- List(3, 2, 5)
    n <- (1 to times)
} yield times
```

Comment: Since `n` is unused, you can `_ <- 1 to times`. No parens there because `<-` is not an operator.

Comment: I actually ended up using this one. The List.fill method worked on the simple weight example I posted here, but not on the more complex generic scenario I am having in reality.

Comment: @AlexanderWeber would be interesting to see the fail case. The flatMaps are similar, produce n intermediate Seqs, tho' the for is easier on the eyes. The fold example avoids the extra colls, like the OP, but requires squinting.

Comment: @som-snytt `myGenericCollection.flatMap(e => { List.fill((e.times)(e) })` caused following error: `no type parameters for method flatMap: (f: MyGenericClass[_] => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B])(implicit bf: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Iterable[MyGenericClass[_]],B,That])That exist so that it can be applied to arguments (MyGenericClass[_] => List[MyGenericClass[_$1(in value $anonfun)]] forSome { type _$1(in value $anonfun) })`

Comment: `--- because ---
argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
 found   : MyGenericClass[_] => List[MyGenericClass[_$1(in value $anonfun)]] forSome { type _$1(in value $anonfun) }
 required: MyGenericClass[_] => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?B]`

Comment: @kreide Interesting. Maybe it's a bug. It works for `Foo[+A]` instead of `Foo[A]`, or `foos.flatMap[Foo[_],List[Foo[_]]](e => ???)` with explicit type args.

Comment: @kreide There are a few bug reports around type inference for existentials: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5579, https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5585

Answer (score 7):

```
initial.flatMap(weight => List.fill(weight.times)(weight))
```

Comment: beat me by about 1 second. Congratulations, you win all the internetz :)

Comment: This works on the described problem, thank you! But unfortunately it didn't work in the generic scenario I am having in reality.

Answer (score 1):

The builder for a List is a ListBuffer.

There is nothing ugly about local mutable state.

```
scala> case class Weight(value: String, weight: Int)
defined class Weight

scala> val ws = List(Weight("a",3),Weight("b",1),Weight("c",2))
ws: List[Weight] = List(Weight(a,3), Weight(b,1), Weight(c,2))

scala> (ListBuffer[Weight]() /: ws) { case (r, w) => 1 to w.weight foreach (_ => r += w); r }
res4: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Weight] = ListBuffer(Weight(a,3), Weight(a,3), Weight(a,3), Weight(b,1), Weight(c,2), Weight(c,2))

scala> .toList
res5: List[Weight] = List(Weight(a,3), Weight(a,3), Weight(a,3), Weight(b,1), Weight(c,2), Weight(c,2))
```

alternatively,

```
scala> (List.empty[Weight] /: ws) { case (r, w) =>
     | var rr = r
     | 1 to w.weight foreach (_ => rr +:= w) ; rr }
res6: List[Weight] = List(Weight(c,2), Weight(c,2), Weight(b,1), Weight(a,3), Weight(a,3), Weight(a,3))

scala> .reverse
res7: List[Weight] = List(Weight(a,3), Weight(a,3), Weight(a,3), Weight(b,1), Weight(c,2), Weight(c,2))
```

worth mentioning

```
scala> for (w <- ws; _ <- 1 to w.weight) yield w.value
res8: List[String] = List(a, a, a, b, c, c)
```

Comment: Thank you for bringing up the possibilities. I went with the last one, though HappyCoder brought it up earlier. Therefore I gave him the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the map method `def flatMap[B](f: (A) ⇒ GenTraversableOnce[B]): TraversableOnce[B]` which is defined for [Iterables](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Iterable), this returns an Iterable that you could transform to a list using the `toList` method.

It's usable like this:

```
val newList = initial.flatMap(weight => List.fill(weight.times)(weight)).toList
```

Comment: What exactly do I put into "transformToSomething" in order to put weight N times into the newList?